# Ask user string input and store in priority queue c++

Tags: c++, queue, priority-queue

How do i ask user a string input and store them in a priority queue? I only know how to ask int data type using priority queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
priority_queue<string> q;
string s;
cin >> s;
q.push(s);
```

Comment: Addendum: This can be done with any structure that has an `operator>>` overload. As a result it is often a good idea to make a `>>` overload for `class`es and `struct`s that will be fed user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::string s;
        std::cout << "enter a string: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, s);
        std::cout << "You entered: " << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```